# PInvoke "Attempted to read or write protected memory"

Tags: c#, c++, c, pinvoke

I'm wrapping a C DLL (which I only have .h's) and I'm stuck with "Attempted to read or write protected memory".

**Info:**

- Windows 7 64-bit
- DLL is 64-bit
- C# App and Wrapper is 64-bit

**Export Def:**

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__SYMBIAN32__)
#define EXP_API __cdecl
#else
    #if !defined(__SYMBIAN32__)
        #define EXP_API
    #else
        #define EXP_API EXPORT_C
    #endif
#endif
```

**Here is the C header struct:**

```
typedef struct bufferstrm bufferstrm_tt;

struct bufferstrm
{
  uint32_t  (EXP_API * bytes_usage)(bufferstrm_tt *bs);

  uint8_t * (EXP_API * get_stuff)(bufferstrm_tt *bs, uint32_t length);


  struct implstrm* some_struct;
};

int32_t EXP_API strmParser(struct bufferstrm_tt *bs);
```

**My C# Wrapper:**

```
[DllImport("Parser.dll", EntryPoint = "strmParser", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int strmParser(ref bufferstrm bs);

// Delegates
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate uint BUFSTRM_bytes_usage(ref bufferstrm bs);
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate IntPtr BUFSTRM_get_stuff(ref bufferstrm bs, uint length);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct bufferstrm
{
   public BUFSTRM_bytes_usage bytes_usage;

   public BUFSTRM_get_stuff get_stuff;

   public IntPtr some_struct;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct implstrm
{
   public uint dummy;
}

public static uint test_bytes_usage(ref bufferstrm bs)
{
   return 0;
}

public static IntPtr test_get_stuff(ref bufferstrm bs, uint length)
{
   return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

**If I use it like this:** [Attempted to read or write protected memory]

```
bufferstrm bs = new bufferstrm();
bs.bytes_usage = BUFSTRM_bytes_usage(test_bytes_usage);
bs.get_stuff = BUFSTRM_get_stuff(test_get_stuff);
implstrm testStruct = new implstrm();
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(testStruct)));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(testStruct, ptr, false);
bs.some_struct = ptr;

int hr = strmParser(ref bs);
```

If I don't set the callbacks it just returns the predicted hr value (which is missing stuff).

Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Enabling "Unmanaged Code Debuggin" I got "Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff". Does this tell you guys anything?

Comment: My first instinct (haven't looked at the code very carefully yet, though) is to double check the calling convention matches on all your delegates/functions/function pointers.

Comment: I've checked and everything is CallingConvention.Cdecl like the DLL headers :/

Comment: Are you sure the C headers are using cdecl though? From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx): `On ARM and x64 processors, __cdecl is accepted and ignored by the compiler.`

Comment: That is a good question and I also saw that article and tried Stdcall and got the same result

Comment: Surely this can be understood by running the failing code in a debugger and inspecting the assembly code?

Comment: Well, I can do that yes. But it is really tricky as you know

Comment: Just tried... same result. Thanks anyway

Comment: So, at least figuring out what kind of instruction it's failing on MAY give you some idea. Without source of the ACTUAL functions, you will have a hard task to solve this - who says that the actual DLL code is correct in the first place?

Comment: Also a good question, but I tried the c++ sample and it worked.

Comment: care to share the code of strmParser and maybe implstrm? I'd guess at first look that it's something to do with returning IntPtr.Zero from your callback and the C code not checking for NULL after calling get_stuff?

Comment: I only have the DLL and implementation headers, I don't have the code.

Comment: use [`fixed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) statement (similar to `pin_ptr` in CLI/C++). Otherwise GC may collect your objects or relocate them.

Comment: Third member is a pointer to a struct. Hans told you that. Why are you ignoring that fact?

Comment: I haven't, I replied "Just tried... same result. Thanks anyway"

Comment: We'll need more information about the error, at least a stack trace or some more debugging information. It really seems like the native code is attempting to dereference NULL (as a result of your `IntPtr.Zero`). I'd suggest modifying your `test_get_stuff` to instead return a valid pointer to some unmanaged memory (allocate it with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, and use the same size in `test_bytes_usage`. And don't forget to `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` after you're done).

Comment: Also, based on your edit (attempt to read at 0xffffffff... aka, -1), it seems the native code is probably unsafe in that it's using (length-1) to index the last item of the data you're feeding it (which has length 0). Try a non-empty array as I've suggested.

Comment: @Cameron On x64 there is only one calling convention. But to write portable code that will be correct on x86 you need to specify cdecl.

Comment: @Mark H... I'm making changes like you said and trying changing return pointer and also using unsafe code. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I still think you should update the question with what you've tried regarding the erroneous struct declaration. And also the docs for the DLL.

Comment: I will! Thank you and please don't read my comments I a bad way... texting is tricky

Comment: It is finally working. Wrote the code in unsafe context and manage memory manually and it is working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't need unsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious mistake in your translation is in the third member of `bufferstrm`

```
struct implstrm* some_struct;
```

This is a pointer to a struct. Based on the name, this struct, provides the actual implementation of the stream. The `bufferstrm` struct wraps that raw stream with a buffering layer. At least, that's what the names suggest.

Now in the C# code, you translated `some_struct` as an in-line struct, rather than a pointer. That is obviously wrong. It should be:

```
public struct bufferstrm
{
   public BUFSTRM_bytes_usage bytes_usage;
   public BUFSTRM_get_stuff get_stuff;    
   public IntPtr some_struct;
}
```

You'll need to use `Marshal.StructureToPtr` to create this pointer.

Beyond that, it seems quite plausible that the two functions that you provide are implemented incorrectly. You've given any details of that the functions are expected to do. Perhaps `get_stuff` is not allowed to return a null pointer. There's no way for us to check any of that because you've only given the prototype of the functions, but omitted details of the semantic rules that the functions must obey.

So I suspect that the delegates you pass are incorrect. But only somebody with knowledge of what they are expected to do can understand how to correct them.

Comment: David I do understand you frustration, because it is mine in the first place. I cannot give what I do not have, as you can see I post de header code, export and c# code. I tried your approach, and might be the first step for the success, but it still returns that nasty exception.

Comment: I think it's going to be hard without docs. The solution to your problem is to contact the vendors and ask for the docs.